# How to pass arguments for multi threading?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am writing a program that can connect multiple clients to a server. I am creating a new thread for each user but am running into error in the multi threading portion

This is my server side code:

```
from socket import*
import threading

server = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('localhost',9000))
        
def handle_client(conn,addr):
    print(addr)
    while(True):
        info = conn.recv(5000).decode()
        if(len(info)>0): 
            print(info[0])
            data = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
            data += "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
            data += "\r\n"
            data += "<html><body>Hello World</body></html>\r\n\r\n"
            conn.sendall(data.encode())
            conn.shutdown(SHUT_WR)
    
  
   
def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"Server is listening on {server}")
    while(True):
        conn,addr = server.accept()# Waits for a connection to start. Returns tuple of connection_object and server address
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client,args=(conn,addr))
        thread.start()
        
start()
```

I am passing the arguments as tuple but for some reason i am still running into error

```
Server is listening on <socket.socket fd=272, family=2, type=1, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 9000)>('127.0.0.1', 50959)
0
Exception in thread Thread-1 (handle_client):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 
1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Arun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 
975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "e:\Desktop\Django\Django_Basics\Django_Basics\WebSockets\WorldsSimplestServer.py", line 25, in handle_client
    info = conn.recv(5000).decode()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Edit: I fixed it by terminating the connection

```
from socket import*
import threading
server = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('localhost',9000))
        
def handle_client(conn,addr):
    print(addr)
    connected = True
    while(connected):
        info = conn.recv(5000).decode()
        if(len(info)>0): 
            print(info[0])
            data = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
            data += "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
            data += "\r\n"
            data += "<html><body>Hello World</body></html>\r\n\r\n"
            conn.sendall(data.encode())
            conn.shutdown(SHUT_WR)
            connected = False
    
  
   
def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"Server is listening on {server}")
    while(True):
        conn,addr = server.accept()# Waits for a connection to start. Returns tuple of connection_object and server address
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client,args=(conn,addr))#Tryng to immitate java cause everyone loves java...
        thread.start()
        
start()
```

Thanks a lot for helping guys!!

Comment: What's the full error? The bottom appears to have been cut off.

Comment: Yeah sorry adding the full error

Comment: Well, for starters, in `handle_client` you `conn.shutdown(SHUT_WR)` but you keep reading from the socket in the infinite loop.

Comment: Oh yeah i am newbie so i didnt notice it. But is that the reason why i am getting the error though?

Comment: Either that or the client is terminating it. It could be that you shutting down the connection causes the client to also terminate, which could cause that error.

Comment: @AnirudhTa yes, that is exactly the reason - you try to `recv()` after `shutdown()` - you can't do this.

Comment: Thanks guys i fixed it by terminating the connection!!